# Accessing a class' running instance from the AppDelegate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

New to Obj-C, I'm trying to trigger a method myMethod of an instance of viewControllerB.
=>viewControllerB is instanciated in viewControllerA.
=>I'm trying to call myMethod from the AppDelegate
=>It seems that anyway I try to do that, It's triggering myMethod in a new instance of viewControllerB

So the question is: how to send a message to an existing instance of a viewController ?

Please explain with code samples since I'm not yet really comfortable with Obj-C.

Thanks !

viewControllerA.m :

```
if (_viewControllerB == nil) {
    self.viewControllerB = [[[ViewControllerB alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewControllerB" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] autorelease];
}
```

viewControllerB.m :

`- (void)myMethod{
    NSLog(@"myMethod!");
}`

AppDelegate.m :  Don't know what tu put here :(

Comment: You need to show us your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get same instance

for (UIViewController *view in self.navigationController.viewControllers)

{

```
if(view isKindOfClass:[viewControllerB class])
{
     [view yourmethodname];
}
```

}

Comment: I want to access the existing instance method FROM the appDelegate.

Comment: in this code I am checking in navigation controller subviews if it returns me the same class as you initiated then i can call the method on same instance...for simplicity first remove if block and then NSLog view in for loop and check console.

Comment: But where should I put this test?

Comment: in app delegate where you want to call method on same instance

Comment: Sorry to be such a noob but how do I NSLog a UIView?

Comment: If I try for (UIView *view in self.tabBarController.view.subviews)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@",view);
    }
 I get: 
2011-03-27 19:27:34.919 myapp[1010:207] <UITransitionView: 0x57478c0; frame = (0 0; 320 431); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x5756bb0>>
2011-03-27 19:27:34.960 myapp[1010:207] <UITabBar: 0x5758c30; frame = (0 431; 320 49); autoresize = W+TM; layer = <CALayer: 0x5758ce0>>
2011-03-27 19:27:35.047 myapp[1010:207] <UIView: 0x5754b10; frame = (0 371; 320 65); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x57485e0>>

Comment: yes its give you all the views in your tabBarcontroller, actually at start up your viewControllerA added in your navigation controller and when you click on the cell in viewControllerA the viewControllerB is pushed in navigation controller...so when you check for self.navigationController.view.subViews it return an array of all the views in navigation controller where can check for the class instance which we want to use for callin method.

Comment: in self.navigationController.view.subView the"navigationController" is the reference variable that you created in appdelegate.h file.

Comment: Got this:  2011-03-27 19:41:08.625 myapp[1093:207] <UINavigationTransitionView: 0x612edb0; frame = (0 0; 320 431); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x612b030>>
2011-03-27 19:41:08.633 myapp[1093:207] <UINavigationBar: 0x612d600; frame = (0 20; 320 44); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x612d750>>

Comment: sorry my mistake its not view its viewControllers so please change it as for(UIViewController *viewcontroller in self.navigationController.viewControllers){ NSLog(@"%@",viewController); }

Comment: Got this if testing with viewControllerA visible :2011-03-27 19:52:26.642 myapp[1208:207] <viewControllerA: 0x612daf0> and this with viewControllerB visible : 
2011-03-27 19:52:26.653 myapp[1208:207] <viewControllerB: 0x573fe50>

Comment: yes it will return only if the viewController is in stack of UINAvigation controller

Comment: Ok, but what do I do with this ?!

Comment: from here you will get the same instance of viewControllerB on which you want to call the method.

Comment: I've edited your answer with the ViewControllers change, you should review it :)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to call the function on the same instance of your viewControllerB then you have to take out that instance from where you added it.

Comment: actually i don't see where you created instance of viewControllerB and where you have added it and also is your viewControllerA added in window.

Comment: Well, my viewControllerA is visible at startup (it's a subview of a NavigationController wich belongs to a tabBarController.
The viewControllerA contains a tableView. The viewControllerA.m code is called when a cell of this tableview is selected.